# Как написать обработку исключения VK API Error 18 «User was deleted or banned»?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Вот таким кодом (используется библиотека vk_requests) пытаюсь получить айдишники друзей юзеров из списка ids:

```
all_ids = list()
for id_ in tqdm(ids):
    counts = api.friends.get(user_id=id_, count=0)['count']  # look at mount of friends
    cycle = min(10, ceil(counts/1000))  # create var with counter which define number of cycles  
    
    for i in range(cycle):
        shift = 0 # var for offset
        friends = api.friends.get(user_id=id_, offset=shift, count=1000)['items']  # get the 1000 friends 
        for friend in friends:
            all_ids.append(friend)
```

Выдаёт ошибку

> VkAPIError: error_code=18,message='User was deleted or
> banned',request_params={'method': 'friends.get', 'oauth': '1', 'v':
> '5.92', 'user_id': '11475787', 'count': '0'}

Как написать исключение для этой ошибки? Если Вам не трудно, объясните как для идиота, спасибо.

Comment: try except пробовали?
https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html

Comment: Попробовал, сработало. До этого не пробовал, потому что эта же схема не работала при попытках получить посты юзеров.

Comment: Но теперь встаёт вопрос почему там, где посты юзеров не выходит.